# Red line through page

Tags: html, stylesheet

I'm going to develop a webpage, with a red line running through the page while scrolling.
Like this one on Teslamotors page:
http://www.teslamotors.com/goelectric#range

The question is whether there is a framework for it, or it can be done with pure HTML? 
And is there a link for a tutorial?

Comment: See [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wants to use parallax effect, [Like this.](http://fearlessflyer.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design/).

Answer (score 0):

Framework `Angularjs` could help you with scroll animations. Here is a tutorial:

http://jjperezaguinaga.com/2013/07/16/angularjs-scroll-animations/